# IOS Swift SwiftUI Firebase "No default Storage bucket found. Did you configure Firebase Storage properly?"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-storage

When I'm trying to run

```
Text("\(imageURL?.absoluteString ?? "placeholder")")
            
        .onAppear(perform: loadImageFromFirebase)
```

which should produce a url for my image in Firebase Storage. I get the error "No default Storage bucket found. Did you configure Firebase Storage properly?", and the preview crashes. The simulator crashes too. I've added

```
override init() {
        super.init()
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
```

to my AppDelegate but this doesn't seem to help.
This is the function which should fetch the url from Firebase:

```
func loadImageFromFirebase() {
        
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "Cessna.jpeg")

        storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            self.imageURL = url!
        }
    }
```

Nothing seems to help. Some advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by disconnecting it from the Firebase project and connecting it again to a new Firebase project. Also re-downloading the firebase .plist file might have done the trick(make sure when you add the .plist file back to xcode that it doesn't have (2) or (3) at the end of its name. Otherwise xcode won't recognize it.) Also added the 'Firebase/Analytics' pod, not sure how, but this might have helped. Hope that this is helpful to whomever might be looking for a solution.